# Why class destructor called if I delete linked list element?

Tags: c++, class, destructor, doubly-linked-list

I want to free memory by deleting all nodes in the end of programm, but I also have function(overloaded operator) to delete specific node. If I'm deleting specific node class destructor is called. Can someone explain why, and how to fix it.

**Class declaration**

```
class StudentList
{
    private:
        typedef struct student_node
        {
            student_node* prevSt;
            
        //######Student DATA######
            string surname;
            string name;
            string father_name;
            Date birthday;
            int year;
            string faculty;
            string departament;
            string group;
            string ID_number;
            string sex; 
        //########################
            SessionList session_data;
            int session_count;
        //########################
        
            student_node* nextSt;       
        }* student_nodePtr;
    
        student_nodePtr headSt;
        student_nodePtr currSt;
        student_nodePtr tailSt;
        student_nodePtr tempSt;
            
    public:
        StudentList();
        ~StudentList();
        StudentList operator-(student_nodePtr selectedSt);
};
```

**Constructor, destructor and overloaded operator**

```
StudentList::StudentList()
{
    headSt = NULL;
    currSt = NULL;
    tailSt = NULL;
    tempSt = NULL;
}

StudentList::~StudentList()
{
    cout << "What!?" << endl;
}

StudentList StudentList::operator-(student_nodePtr selectedSt)
{
    if(headSt == NULL || selectedSt == NULL)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    
    if(headSt == selectedSt)
    {
        headSt = selectedSt->nextSt;
    }
    
    if(tailSt == selectedSt)
    {
        tailSt = selectedSt->prevSt;
    }
    
    if(selectedSt->prevSt != NULL)
    {
        selectedSt->prevSt->nextSt = selectedSt->nextSt;
    }
    
    delete selectedSt;
    return *this;
}
```

[Here i'm choosing to Delete (2 2 2 2) guy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j57q5.png)

[Here destructor appears for some reason](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o34DJ.png)

Comment: First of all, you don't need `typedef` in C++. All structure or class names are type-names.

Comment: Please provide a [example]. Right now I don't know how you're running the program, what input you're giving the program, and what output you're seeing.

Comment: Please change your destructor to give you more information: `cout << "What!?: " << this << endl;` -- Then ask yourself, where did that object come from.  You will see that it is a different `StudentList` object than the one you are using in the calling function.

Comment: Also, the only functions in the `StudentList` object that are accessible are `StudentList()`, `~StudentList()` and `operator -`.  So how exactly are you able to write a program that does anything to `StudentList` if everything else is `private`?

Comment: I'm sorry, I posted it like that because I was sure that the problem is in this part of code

Comment: Don't post images of text. Copy the text instead so it is more accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've declared your `operator-` like this:

```
    StudentList operator-(student_nodePtr selectedSt);
```

Note that it is returning a `StudentList` object **by-value**.  That means that the calling code is receiving a temporary `StudentList` object, which then gets destroyed when it goes out of scope; hence the call to the `StudentList` destructor.

The usual way to declare an operator like that would by to have it return a reference instead:

```
    StudentList & operator-(student_nodePtr selectedSt);
```

... that way no temporary `StudentList` object is created, but calls to the operator can still be chained together if desired.

Answer (score 0):

In returning `*this` as `StudentList`, you're creating a *temporary* object and returning that - this causes a destructor call. I think this will *work,* even in a statement like:

```cpp
myList = myList - oneEntry - anotherEntry - aThird;
```

That's because the temporary created at each subtraction is used for the next subtraction, and the final temporary is what gets assigned to `myList`.

However, every single one of those subtractions will probably result in a *new* temporary, which is going to get rather expensive, especially for larger lists.

You would be better off returning a reference, `StudentList&`, so that no temporaries are necessary and the original object is returned.

---

More problematic in your code is that, given the students form a *doubly* linked list, you should probably have something in `operator-` that adjusts the reverse-direction pointer as well as the forward one.

Your current implementation correctly handles empty lists and deleting the head/tail, but then goes on to do *just* this:

```cpp
if(selectedSt->prevSt != NULL) {
    selectedSt->prevSt->nextSt = selectedSt->nextSt;
}
```

This adjusts the previous node (if any) so that it now points to the following node. However, and following node will still point to the one about to be deleted as its previous node. In other words, this scenario will ensue:

```
+------+                       +------+
| node |---------------------->| node |
|      |                    +--|      |
+------+  +--------------+  |  +------+
          | deleted node |<-+
          +--------------+
```

You'll need to do *both* directions to keep a consistent doubly-linked list:

```cpp
if(selectedSt->prevSt != NULL) { // forward link (already done).
    selectedSt->prevSt->nextSt = selectedSt->nextSt;
}
if(selectedSt->nextSt != NULL) { // backward link (need to add).
    selectedSt->nextSt->prevSt = selectedSt->prevSt;
}
```

Without that, your list is going to become corrupted and cause serious problems if you ever decide to traverse in the reverse direction.